# how to activate the function keys without having to click the button in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

how to activate the function keys without having to click the button in J2ME? for example :
in form RECEIVE MESSAGE have button Command REPLY, so...how to activate Command REPLY without having to click the button? if using TIMER, how the source code?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can try TimerTask class and at a particular time period call a commandAction with the keycode of RECEIVE MESSAGE Button.  Look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/extendsTimerTask.htm) Example

You Need to call CommandAction Method in to its Run Method.